# Usage the SignalR library

Tags: c#, api, signalr

Hub.cs file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignalRCoreServer.Hubs
{
    public class ViewHub : Hub

    {
        public async Task SendRadio(string radio ,string shazam)
        {
             await Clients.Others.SendAsync("ReceiveRadio",radio, shazam);
        }  
    }
}
```

site.js file

```
 "use strict";

var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/radioHub").build();
//const jsonFile = 'radioChannel.json';

function processData(  ) {
    fetch("https://shazam.p.rapidapi.com/songs/get-detailskey=?&locale=en-US", {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "x-rapidapi-host": "shazam.p.rapidapi.com",
            "x-rapidapi-key": "1ab8f??????????"
        }
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });

}



document.getElementById("radioPlayer").disabled = false;

connection.on("ReceiveRadio", function (radio, shazam) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    document.getElementById("songNameList").appendChild(li);

    li.textContent = `${radio} return ${shazam}`;

     
});

connection.start().then(function () {
    document.getElementById("radioPlayer").disabled = false;
    var radio = document.getElementById("radioPlayer").value;
    var shazam = processData();
    console.log(shazam)
    connection.invoke("SendRadio", radio, shazam).catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
    });

}).catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

index.cshtml

```
  @page
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    
    
    <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <audio controls  src="https://us4.internet-radio.com/proxy/douglassinclair?mp=/stream;" ></audio>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <audio id="radioPlayer" src="https://us4.internet-radio.com/proxy/douglassinclair?mp=/stream;" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <ul id="songNameList"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
```

radioChannel.json

```
{
    "Stations": [
        {
            "Name": "channel1",
            "Url": "https: //us4.internet-radio.com/proxy/douglassinclair?mp=/stream;"
            
        }
       
   
}
```

In order to learn the names of the songs playing on the radio, I need to send data to  shazam api using the signalR library.
Can we send data directly in dataProcess function in javascript file? Which way should I go?Songs are playing in index.html but I couldn't find way to send it to  shazam.